# Tool to fire up EC2 instance and SSH in?

Tags: amazon-ec2

It's a fairly common thing that I want to fire up a clean EC2 instance of a particular version of Ubuntu (usually lucid or precise) and then SSH in to that instance once it's up.

I've got some Python code that I use to do it for projects (lp:pkgme-service, lp:lp-dev-utils), but I was wondering whether there's a command-line tool.

- I tried `ubuntu-ec2-run`. It doesn't use a security group that opens up SSH, so I would have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

The [cloud-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cloud-utils) [image: Install cloud-utils] package contains a tool called `ubuntu-ec2-run` that lets you fire up clean instances, I'm not sure on the ssh bit.

You can also do this with juju if you've got it configured with ec2 with:

```
juju deploy ubuntu
juju ssh ubuntu/0
```

Comment: `ubuntu-ec2-run` fires up the instance, but needs quite a lot of extra configuration to open up a port for SSH and set up a valid SSH key pair. (-g <existing-security-group> -k <name-of-keypair>)

Comment: Configuring Juju with ec2 took a while. The `ubuntu` charm is currently broken but I fetched it with `bzr branch lp:charms/ubuntu` and used the local repository option to deploy it. After juju reports a successful deployment, I had to wait a while (about two minutes) before I could see a public IP in `juju status`. Even then, `juju ssh ubuntu` doesn't work. I had to type `juju ssh ubuntu/0`.

Comment: "juju ssh ubuntu" won't work, since "ubuntu" is the service, which could consist of multiple units (machines).